# Please help me choose a Chinese name that is easy to write and is a name

Tags: names

My (western) Kindergartener son needs a Chinese name (three characters) for himself for use at his school. I started with some ideas that relate to his western names, one character for family name, two characters for given name. I'm mainly looking to avoid names that would not be actual names (e.g., doorhandle and lightswitch) in the traditional sense. Please give me feedback on my shortlist of characters and what combinations would work.

**1. Family name:**

a. 庞 – Páng

b. 潘 – Pān

**2. Given name:**

a. 德明 - dé míng - "bright virtue"? I'm puzzled by this one because it's a homophone for 得名 which I understand to mean "named after something". Is this homophone distracting?

<s>b. 德懋 - dé mào - "diligent / hard-working virtue" (name to live up to)</s>  second character is too unusual

<s>c. 凤雏 – fèng chú – fledgling phoenix, handsome and spirited youth (apt description of the boy)</s>  is unsuitable

d. 从 - Cóng - I just like the sound

e. 德维 - Déwéi - “Of great principle”

f. 德治 - Dézhì - "rule by setting an example"

Thank you for reading. Open to any and all feedback.

ETA: I appreciate all the feedback, it's exactly what I was hoping for. I've added a few other options and updated the question to try to appease the mods.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132787/discussion-on-question-by-m-p-please-help-me-choose-a-chinese-name-that-is-easy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Chinese name need your birth day date and hour to be a good name.
if you interest it you can give it to me and I will work one out for you.

凤雏 is a joke now. if you take this name you will be a joke.

——————————————————————————————————————————————
your son was born 2016-02-27 5am it is
(you not say before or after 5am I do as it 5:00)
丙申年庚寅已卯日**丁卯时(if it is before5:00 then it is 丙寅)**

丙申庚寅已卯丁卯
your son's 五行 is 土

to 五行 is

火金水土

金木火土

土木

火木

金:2
木:3
水:1
火:3
土:3

for balance

you should use 水 for one word.

so what about:

庞/潘-

微霖

盈厚

繁洵

the most important I think is that you can speak out it loudly.

think the scene

you and your son is in the street play together and your son is a bit far from you and you want to take him home.

or in the classroom your son's classmate want to call him to eat dinner.

you/your son's classmate will speak his name loudly. your son's name can be

called out smoothly(or I do not know what to say it you can try it).

If the name is good to speak out. your son's classmate will have a will to call me. it is good.

but if you take 凤雏 as your son's name, he will be jeer(or other) by his classmate.

**Just a advice.**

you may take other name as you want.

Comment: I don't know we have a 風水大師 on the forum :)

Comment: @r13 -- His moniker, "daotian", 道 天, should have alerted you?  :)

Comment: @WayneCheah Yeah, Ｉ thought it was "稻田" (my bad pin-yin :).

Comment: I am interested, @daotian. Son was born 2016-02-27 5am. Thanks!

Comment: @daotian -- How is the work on OP's request coming along? I, for one, am truly interested. I myself consulted an astrologer when choosing a name for my daughter .

Comment: eidted @MP please check

Comment: @WayneCheah I have edited it.

Comment: It looks like the family name 潘 would satisfy the proposal to include 水 because of the water radical, right?

Comment: @MP the balance is important.if you use 潘 then better use 土 in one word in name. too more 水 is not good too.and what is important too. is your temperature( I do not know what to say it in english). if you are interest it you can tell me some big thing in your life which impress you a lot. for example some thing you are very happy or regret or do something wrong. to get a good name you may take half a day talk to someone give you the name.

Comment: @daotian -- ".... what is important too. is your temperature ( I do not know what to say it in English) Perhaps you could say it in Chinese and we can try and translate as best we can? It must be gotten right from the very start because nothing is more important than a person's name.

Comment: @WayneCheah ok. 父亲的性格对你的女儿也是有影响的，你可以思考一下自己，建议你说一下你遇到过的事情，比较让你印象深刻的，这样可以看出你的性格，可以辅助给你女儿的名字达到一个比较好的平衡。假如你的性格比较冲动，容易跟别人发生矛盾，那么你的女儿的名字就要缓和一点。

Comment: @WayneCheah 这只是我个人的看法，仅供参考

Comment: My rough summary. "A father's 性格, character affects his children. Reflecting, 思考, on what you consider impactful past experiences, 遇到过...印象深刻的, would depict your character which would assist, 辅助, in giving your child's name a good balance, 好的平衡。If the character is impulsive / confrontational, 冲动, then the child's name should have more "soothing", "comforting", 缓和, features"

Comment: @daotian -- This idea of examining the parent's character would involve certain personal matters which OP may not want to divulge here. So, if OP still want to pursue this line of inquiry, perhaps it should be done privately, say, through Email? Just a suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps now we can see why the Chinese, especially the older generation, pays so much attention when it comes to naming their children. This is because every Chinese character has meaning; most with multiple meanings. And so the "meaning" of the characters, singly or in combination, in a person's name would, sympathetically, affect the personality / character and even the destiny of that person. A kind of "vibrational transference" of energy, positive / negative, from the name to the person so named. Mix in the character of the parent and the complexity is astronomical. It's mind boggling.

Comment: Yes usually private things will take face to face and not leave words and we will forget it the other day.and the names will be write in an paper and will never give the same name to another children. through email is not good since it is private thing. I just say it to you and it does not matter too may. if a name is 95 and it may be 98 will these private thing.@WayneCheah

Comment: yes if will affect the personality.if you know chinese history you can see the 明dynasty. the  emperor and his children use (only for boy not girls) each generation for a 五行.to tell the truth I do not know how it affect a person and maybe I am not right.I just try my best to do it.